# Embed a web to case in LLWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, web-to-case

We have a web to case running on our website. We have also developed a consumer portal using Salesforce community. And the plan now is to add the web to case form on the portal.
Is there an easy way of moving the web to case form code on the lwc, to avoid the duplication of work?
Please suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your W2C form is designed.

First, if it's just static HTML, you can copy-paste the HTML directly into an LWC, it'll work without modification.

Alternatively, if you have JavaScript as well, then you would want to consider using an iframe to embed the W2C form.

A third option would be to copy the HTML portion into an LWC, then write some JavaScript logic in the controller to handle validation, etc. At that point, there would be some extra duplication of effort, since the script and controller would be separate, but this should be minimal for most forms.

Alternatively, assuming your hosting site can handle custom scripts, you could rewrite the entire W2C as an LWC component, and then use [LWS OSS](https://lwc.dev/) or [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lightning_out) to render the form outside of Salesforce with no extra effort once the form has been built.

Finally, you can theoretically just use some other framework and embed that framework in both places. It is conceptually possible to run React, Vue, Angular, jQuery, etc inside of LWC with some effort, so an app built in those frameworks could serve as a W2C in both use cases.